# Magento submit review

Tags: ajax, magento, submit, review

When I submit a review in Magento I receiving this code..

```
{"success":true,"msg":"
```

Thanks for your review! Your review has been accepted for moderation.</span></li></ul></li></ul>"}

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: do you want to hide these : `{"success":true,"msg":"  & </span></li></ul></li></ul>" } , you can use template path hints to check from which file it is coming and take backup of file and you can hide it...... also you can use search those words using `fgrep -r "success":true,"msg":"` if you have ssh access......

Answer (score 0):

This is message shows while you submit review. That review is in "Pending" state.
Admin need to approve that review, after that it will be visible on frontend.